# How to print details status when RestTemplate request failure?

Tags: spring, networking, tcp

I use resttemplate to call a link such as http://example/jsonObject,about 4000 times a minute ,In most time it is fine, but sometime resttemplate will throw 60 times above exceptions in a minute.

```
restTemplate error org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://example/jsonObject": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:751)
```

I use code:

```
    try {
        CouponV2ResultVO couponV2ResultVO = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example/jsonObject", CouponV2ResultVO.class);
        long expense = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs;
        log.info("takes {} {} ms", expense);
        return couponV2ResultVO;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        long expense = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs;
        log.error("takes {} ms", expense, couponReqFullUri, ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        throw e;
    }
```

I want to print a more complete detail such as tcp communication between the whole request when resttemplate failure, or any other usage information instead of juat a timeout exception.Is it possible?

Comment: I think you got everything you need with this exception. It is obvious that there is an issue on network level either on your side or on the other side. And most of the time you can not do anything to do with it on application side apart from changing the timeout durations and maybe catching it which is also not useful most of the time except for retries. What else do you want to see?

Comment: @cool I think you are right, there is not good method to solve tiemout problem.But when some request error, other request is still ok, so I think it may be some incomplete data transfer in tcp level, if I get that, maybe I can discover more detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `log.error(e)` or `e.printStackTrace` instead of `throw e`, when you want to have more details about an exception.

Comment: I have print the stacktrace, but it is useless.